# Select option in dropdown in Selenium WebDriver in Jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to select values from the dropdown using Selenium WebDriver in JMeter. I am using the below code, but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
var selectCity = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("cityName"));
    selectCity.selectByVisibleText("Washington");
```

Could anyone please help me with the same? (All i am getting are the solutions in Java, which doesnt seem to be working in Jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you made a typo, I believe you need to change this line:

```
var selectCity = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("cityName"));
                                        ^ ka-boom
```

to this one:

```
var selectCity = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("cityName"));
```

because [findElements](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function returns the **List** of WebElements and my expectation is that you need only one.

Also double check that this is really a [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), in modern web applications it might be the case that something which looks like a dropdown is basically a  [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) which looks like a dropdown due to [CSS styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

And last but not the least, it's possible to run [Java code from JavaScript](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) or you can just switch to `groovy` language which is very close to Java. See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article for more details if needed

Comment: Thanks that worked!! It seems half of my problem are due to this, findElement(s) issue. Thanks for pointing it out.